# Implementing terrains in XNA similar to Battle Zone (1980)

Tags: windows-phone-7, 3d, xna, terrain

I am developing a 3D game for Windows Phone that includes terrains and volcanoes at infinite distance similar to Battle Zone (1980) by Atari Inc. The player can never touch the terrains no matter how far player drives. Currently, to implement this I am mapping a 2D texture inside the wall of cylinder. The cylinder is also moving with the player so that the player can never reach terrains. I am not sure whether this is a good method to implement terrains as I am facing problems like distortion of texture when mapping it on the wall of cylinder.

Please suggest me methods to implement a view of terrains in XNA similar to Battle Zone?

Comment: Certainly the method you are using is good enough , but do you have any specific concerns? Why do you think it isn't good enough? Elaborate a little in the question.

Comment: As I am developing a 3D game for the first time, I wasn't sure whether the method used is good or not. Also, I needed volcano eruption with the terrain so I was using multiple frames for the eruption animation. But now I tried particle system for the animation of volcano eruption and it is working well. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

normally instead of cylinder developers use box (so-called SkyBox)

[image]

It has less polygons and in general less distortion (could be some at edges)

To make it look more real some devs  like Valve use off-screen render in first pass that include skybox + some distant models with low details and moving cloud sprites or textured ring with alpha. Both points of view are synchronised (main camera and off-screen camera)   then (without clearing colour buffer) they render final scene on top. Thanks to that far building will move a bit and scene surrounding will look less plain. To avoid z-buffer cleaning between passes they simply doing first pass under the floor(literally) of the scene of main pass.

Comment: Thanks. As I am new to 3D game development, I don't have much idea about sky-box, off-screen rendering, etc. Therefore, can you please provide me with some good links that covers the implementation of overall scene for a 3D game? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I believe there is no simple reading for this. You have 2 ways. First one: Learn your graphic engine possibilities and rely only on them in your project. Most of the stuff is deep inside engine core and you may never need to know how it works.  But you will need to profile your code width and depth since you have no deep understanding how it works in the basic lvl. When you spot problem - ask on the stackoverflow or engine forum.

Comment: and the second way : get good fresh book on 3D API-s, software for devices development, algorithms, linear algebra etc. Find open-source engine and learn how it works. It will take a lot of time and effort but you will be able to write good code.